# Gimp gimp_image_convert_color_profile_from_file does not work

Tags: gimp, gimpfu, python-fu

I'm trying to automate some task with gimp but it seems so that the color profile converting does not work.

```
pdb.gimp_image_convert_color_profile_from_file(image, r"d:\Todelete\Input\eciRGB v2.icc", 1, TRUE)
```

I tried with different icc files,from python, from console, with gimpfu script , I tried every plugin method:

```
pdb.gimp_image_convert_color_profile(image, num_bytes, color_profile, intent, bpc)
pdb.gimp_image_convert_color_profile_from_file(image, uri, intent, bpc)
pdb.gimp_image_set_color_profile(image, num_bytes, color_profile)
pdb.gimp_image_set_color_profile_from_file(image, uri)
```

Every time I got "operation not supported" error message

Meanwhile i came out with a solution that I use ImageMagick with a batch file, but this problem is still bothering me. Am I doing something wrong or are the functions buggy?

Comment: Works for me (a least `gimp_image_convert_color_profile_from_file(...)`). Can you post the actual code in your quesion (preferably Python?). What are the values of the arguments?

Comment: Actually if I write it into the Gimp console is enough:
'>>> from gimpfu import *
>>> image = gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> profile_name, profile_desc, profile_info = pdb.plug_in_icc_profile_file_info(r"d:\Todelete\Input\GIMP built-in sRGB.icc")
>>> pdb.gimp_message(profile_info) #it worked, the icc file could be read
>>> pdb.gimp_image_convert_color_profile_from_file(image, r"d:\Todelete\Input\GIMP built-in sRGB.icc", 1, TRUE) #this is the problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Operation not supported
>>>'